# Error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Produit'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in angular and since 5 days i am getting "**ERROR in src/app/modifier-produit/modifier-produit.component.ts(23,7): error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Produit'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'idProduit' is missing in type 'Object'.**" in my IDE console

Someone could please me to find what i did wrong?

**Produit model**

```
export class Produit {
    idProduit:any;
    designationProduit:string='';
    prixAchatProduit:number=0;
    prixVenteProduit:number=0;
}
```

**my ts File**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modifier-produit',
  templateUrl: './modifier-produit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modifier-produit.component.css']
})
export class ModifierProduitComponent implements OnInit {

  produit:Produit=new Produit();
  idProduit:number;

  constructor(private service:ProduitService, private router:Router, private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    this.idProduit = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['idProduit'];
   }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.service.editOneProduit(this.idProduit).subscribe(data => {
      this.produit=data;
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add type for response

```
this.service.editOneProduit(this.idProduit).subscribe((data: Produit) => {
```